# How do I run Chrome for Testing in my launch.json file?

Tags: json, google-chrome, chrome-for-testing, cft

I am making a web app in VSCode. I recently found out about [Google Chrome *for Testing,*](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) so I decided to use it instead of regular Chrome, which I've been using since the beginning. I've had no issues with normal Chrome (I used the Live Server extension, went live, and set the `launch.json` file to that localhost.)

So, I tried to add `"runtimeExecutable": "C:/Users/*****/Downloads/chrome-win64/chrome-win64/chrome.exe",` to my `launch.json`, (that's where Chrome for Testing is,) and I got faced with this error:

```
Unable to launch browser: "spawn
C:/Users/*****/Downloads/chrome-win64/chrome-win64/chrome.exe ENOENT"
```

However, I saved it as a web app in Chrome for Testing, and it worked fine. Can someone please explain this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`ENOENT` means the file wasn’t found. I suspect the fix is to use double backslashes (`C:\\Users\\…`) for the executable as you’re on Windows.